# scrapy "ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up"

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to follow an easy tutorial on scrapy.org (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

so I have itemps.py

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

and dmoz_spider.py

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

[But I get this terminal with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlctf.png)

I use PowerShell. Scrapy 1.0.5 and Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: What is the filename? You can't have slashes / in posix filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code into your `settings.py` file.

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
  's3': None,
}
```

Or update scrapy, this [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1054) was fixed in release 1.1

Comment: Thanks I added that and I don't get errors anymore but still "Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)" so it's not working

Comment: You should fill and `yield` your `DmozItem` in `parse` method

Comment: I'm sorry but I didnt't understand what you meant...what shoud i do in parse metthod?

Comment: This is info from scrapy docs `Now, check the files in the current directory. You should notice two new files have been created: Books.html and Resources.html, with the content for the respective URLs, as our parse method instructs.` Do you check the files?